# Count consecutive blank cells between non-blank cells in a column

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to count the number of blank cells between two non-blank cells in a column.  Specifically two dates and days between those two dates.

I've tried `COUNTBLANK` and various other formulas I've found on here and other similar sites, but I'm either modifying them incorrectly, or they're simply not what I'm looking for.

[My sample worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x1jEyfWEfveGICbIlVeriDENu2yYLM4501bjfb87AtA/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consecutive resetting count is done like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)="", MMULT(N(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)))), N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)=""))-HLOOKUP(0, MMULT(N(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))>TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)))), N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)="")), MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), IF(N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)<>G1:G), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), ), 1, 1), VLOOKUP(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), IF(N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)<>G1:G), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), ), 1, 1), 0), 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(iF(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)="", MMULT(N(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)))), N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)=""))-HLOOKUP(0, MMULT(N(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))>TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)))), N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)="")), MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), IF(N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)<>G1:G), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), ), 1, 1), VLOOKUP(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), IF(N(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)<>G1:G), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), ), 1, 1), 0), 0), )=1, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({IF(INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0),, 1)="", MMULT(N(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)))), N(INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0),, 1)=""))-HLOOKUP(0, MMULT(N(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))>TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)))), N(INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0),, 1)="")), MATCH(VLOOKUP(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), IF(N(INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0),, 1)<>{"×"; INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0),, 1)}), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), ), 1, 1), VLOOKUP(ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), IF(N(INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0),, 1)<>{"×"; INDEX(SORT({
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0),, 1)}), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1)), ), 1, 1), 0), 0), ), ROW(
 INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1))}, 2, 0), 999^99, 1), ), "offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer! Is it possible to reverse it so that it counts down instead of up? So H9 would be 3?

Comment: most likely no. but if you are interested in a draggable solution it could be done and also to look exactly like you want it to be.

Comment: @Trey nevermind, everything is possible. answer updated

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution provided by player0, I created an extra sheet and entered in cell I2

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(G2:G), iferror(vlookup(G2:G, query({if(row(G2:G) <= max(if(not(isblank(F2:F)), row(G2:G))),vlookup(row(G2:G),filter({row(G2:G),G2:G},len(G2:G)),2),), --isblank(G2:G)}, "Select Col1, Sum(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1"), 2, 0)),))
```

See if that works?